How does God’s love and goodness follow logically?
According to some religions and philosophers/theologians, the existence of God follows logically because there must be someone to create the universe. (The first cause argument.)
However, in many of these religions, there's an assumption that this God is loving. How did the assumption that he is loving originate? At best we can say that he is neutral but I am unable to find any solid reasoning for his love.
I'm curious about Sikhism in specific but also interested in other religions that have the same assumption.
As asked by @JoWehler, here are some references to how Sikhism describes God. From Japji Sahib pauri 5:

thaapi-aa na jaa-ay keetaa na ho-ay. aapay aap niranjan so-ay.
He cannot be established; By doing it cannot be done. He Himself is Immaculate and Pure.

Again from pauri 5 :

jin sayvi-aa tin paa-i-aa maan. naanak gaavee-ai gunee niDhaan.
Whoever serves Him receives honor. O Nanak sing – “Only Lord has endless Virtues”.

Here they call God pure and virtuous. Other religions make similar claims. How have theologians argued that God is loving/good?

It does not... It is part of some views about god. The gods of ancient Greek religion (Homer) hate and love. The god of Aristotle 's Metaphysics is the object of love but he does not care of us.

@harjotdhillon I understand your question. You could improve the question by giving some carefully chosen specific references. Possibly also by restricting to one specific religion. Not speaking about religion in general. See Mauro’s comment.

@JoWehler my intentions were to ask about Sikhism in specific but later realised that thus apply to every religion and very few people would have information about Sikhism. It would also involve a lot of translation from ancient Gurmukhi to English. Anyway I would look for English translations wait for some time I am in classroom currently.

@harjotdhillon Are your quotes from pauri 5 (not six)? See https://www.sikhiwiki.org/index.php/Japji_Sahib_Pauri_5 - Anyhow the text is just praising, it is not a philosophical text. One cannot draw any logical conclusion because the text does not present any arguments.

Problem with every reference I know is that they are written in 2nd person tone. So instead of religious reference you can see wikipedia page. It also says that god is kind and merciful. See in attribute section

@harjotdhillon Thanks for the references. But it seems that the texts are just praising, not giving arguments for their praises. That's often the same also in other religions. Hence one can conclude nothing about the praised being, only about the viewpoints of those who praise.

You may find better answers asking on Hinduism SE using the Sikhism tag. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sikhism

My answer here may be of some interest. Note also that while God as willing the good of all people is mostly a universal in the classical theisms, God having affection for all people is not; and willing the good doesn't mean willing the pleasant. See e.g. Quran 3:32, Psalm 11:5.

Also possibly of interest: Catechism of the Catholic Church paragraphs 214-231.

My intentions were to ask about Sikhism.. Harjot:This should be part of the question. but later realised that thus [I assme 'this'] apply to every religion it's not so straightforward!! See @gs comment above. Though you can add it in as your take on the matter. Religions come in all shapes and colors and present themselves in any number of ways. Trying to paint them all with broad brushstrokes will inevitably land you with Christian framing, Christian support and most importantly Christian rejects. You can take it as norm that all atheistic/secular answers here are Christian framed(1/2)

The most obvious telltale sign of a Christian worldview and framing is that the discussion will be framed in terms of xyz-theism — poly/mono/a (more fancy ones like heno ) etc. Nothing wrong with that if that's what you want but if not you need to demarcate the question more narrowly. If x calls himself an atheist he's a christian atheist by default (eg. A Hindu or Sikh atheist would call himself nastik charvak etc which has a totally different meaning)(2/2)

I submitted an edit, mostly for grammar, but also to incorporate Mauro's point about "some views". Hopefully I didn't change the meaning of the question, though. @harjotdhillon please feel free to revert anything if my summary leaves anything out/has anything you dislike.

How is a straightforward question on theology and logic any more or less "opinion-based" than any other question on philosophy?  This "close anything that involves any reference to religion" campaign is out of control.

Logic is not the right method to find an answer to God questions.  This point was made by Kant in his Critique of Pure Reason.
Whether there is a God in our universe or not, and if so what that God or Gods Propeties are, is now considered an empirical question, not a logical one.  Most theologians before Kant tried to derive God properties from reasoning, but this project is doomed if the world and what is in it is contingent, not necessary.
As all sorts of DIFFERENT Gods have been claimed, with different properties, which one if any might exist is clearly not derivable by logic.
Non-empirical arguments, like "first cause" etc., are in current theological thinking not "proofs" but plausible rationales or "warrants" for considering a God claim or version.
One of these plausible rationales has been deployed in favor of monotheism -- that a simpler and more pure religion is possible within monotheism than polytheism, or diffuse Hindu pluralism.  Then among monotheists, there are comparative claims about relative degree of monotheism, with Muslims claiming Islam is more monotheistic than Christianity (due to the Christian Trinity doctrine), and Jews claiming Judaism is more monotheistic than Islam (no semi-divine special messenger needed).  In this comparison, Sikhism actually "wins" the most monotheistic prize, as Sikhism holds that EVERYTHING IS GOD, and our belief in our and the world's separateness and individual existence is -- delusion.  Maya. Note this is neither a logical nor an empirical justification of Sikhism, but more of a rhetorical one.
Is a monotheistic God loving?  There is actually a strong empirical case against this, as the property of being loving is not consistent with the brutality and cruelty that is embedded in so much of our world. The failed empirical test case of the postulate of "God is all powerful and loving" is called the Problem of Evil.  We have good empirical evidence against this claim.
The REASON to think that a God is loving, is generally based on mystic insights.  Those who claim to commune with a God, often say the God IS loving. This is from direct first person experience.
The conflict between this empirical evidence for Love, the theology of monotheism, and the empirical failed test case of the Problem of Evil, is resolvable if one abandons monotheism for di-theism.
While Christianity, or Hinduism, could be adapted to be di-theistic (the first heretic, Marcion, was a di theist Christian), the "most absolute absolutism" status of Sikhism which I mentioned above does not allow this to be a plausible variant of Sikhism.

V interesting take — tnx! The monotheism claims of Christianity are wrong on so many levels it's hard to know where to begin!  Also the loving ness of God as a mystic empiric fact is notable. The only arguable point is that Oneness of God → theodicy. Well yes if you're an ordinary person and no if you're a mystic who has experience (and immersion) in God. In any case if you = I =all=God then the question of cruelty evil etc is moot... unless we're claiming Divine masochism

@Rushi -- I am a mystic.  But I =/= God per my experience.  My experiences support di-theism, plus multiple other spiritual entities.

In Nonduality, the equal or not equal idea does not arise.

@ScottRowe Dualisms are the key feature of learning about the universe.  Me/not-me.  Food/not-food.  Friendly/hostile.  Non-dual babies do not survive to toddlerhood.  Learning exceptions to dualities -- IE some hostiles can be befriended.  Some non-food can be turned into food, is just more caveats on dualities, IE TIERS of dualities.  I consider non-duality to be not just wrong, but actively harmful.

Toddlers don't have to worry about God. But then, neither does anyone else. I was responding to your mystic comment. There are 0 kinds of mystics: those who are nondual, and those who are not.

@ScottRowe Prompted by this dialogue, I found a better link on nonduality (that sikhs call Oneness, ik Onkaar). The oneness link in my answer is changed to that, a 3-4 minutes video

@ScottRowe   In any case nonduality is a heart matter not a mind matter. One of the big contributors to the sikh corpus Kabir

@Rushi ok, I guess I wouldn't necessarily categorize it as heart or mind (or both etc) but it does seem that it is not amenable to discursive thought. Conscious verbal things like this site are not where it will be discovered, considered, understood, and so on. That's not a problem, to me the problem is that most folks know nothing about it and seem to resist learning. It would be like spending all of life sitting down and having no interest in hiking, dancing, swimming and so on. Why do humans go in to ego and shut the door behind them? Come out and play! Life is short!

Many +1s for the above @ScottRowe! Except for the juxtaposition: "Conscious verbal things" Seems like an oxymoron to mix »conscious« and »verbal« No? (Our use of language is among the more mechanical aspects of our life) 3-way oxymoron if you consider that thinginess cannot be with either. But anyways... I take your suggestion more seriously. To consider that this site is a waste of time

@ScottRowe I disagree that "it" is not amenable to discursive thought. A discourse that I THINK addresses your interest is Virtues.  There are Virtues that we should make part of our personality.  Classical Virtue thinking has a multiplicity of practical virtues, modern virtue thinking postulates a "higher" set that matter more:  Truth, Love, Beauty.  I became convinced of the wisdom of Virtue ethics by discourse, and that Truth, my prior guiding flame, was less important than Love.  In more recent discourse, I have realized there is a 4th higher virtue, and that is Agency, or Vigorousness.

@Rushi Agency -- applying Vigor to Living, is I believe what Kabir was extolling.  And through "discourse" I have recognized the validity of this value.  And through discourse I recognized  the blindness and narrowness of most Western philosophy, in that "truth" is the only higher value that it recognizes and pursues.  I reference back to Socrates, who taught the importance of questioning and examining the walls of the boxes one thinks within.  Also, if you do not realize we also think non-verbally, tell me the verbal thoughts you have while looking at a sunset ....  See discourse is useful!

To both -- The importance of Vigorous Living is a theme I discovered. among the Process Theologian movement.  Here is a summary of Process Theology, and its embrace of Virtues thinking: https://ctr4process.org/article/whiteheadian-suggestions-for-process-theology/  Because life is "process", IE change/action, a 4th virtue of Action/Engagement/Vigor is easily discovered within this view.  Thomas Oord and Tripp Fuller are popular process theologians with podcasts who emphasize the virtue of Agency, or "Spiciness".

If you see my answer, it's a 'discourse' on what everyone knows as a primary experience/qualia but is essentially not ' discourse-able' — Love. Yes there are some of us here who see no contradiction in that. Some evidently do — see the vote record of my answer

@Rushi -- I m one of the two upvotes on your answer.  However, i agree with the criticism of it by Peter Klocking -- you have not provided any reason why God must be like a three legged stool (arguments by analogy are -- inherently not actually arguments), nor why one of the legs must be Love.  If it "just happens to be the case for our world and God", then there IS no necessity, and the justification is empirical relative to multiple possible different contingencies.  which is my answer here.  God in our universe happens to have the character of Love, but this was not necessary.

Tnx for the upvote. Still more for the explanation. I can only say a big area of disagreement is God is contingent/empirical vs necessary. Maybe we understand these words differently. But for me a non necessary God would not be worth having as God.  (I happen to think Anselm got it more right than most of his detractors) For the other points of Phil I dont really disagree: Love is not a subject for discussion. But one can be reminded that we all know it. As for the 3-legged stool — sure its not necessary!! I just picked the 3 cardinal teachings of sikhism

I wanted to add: I find the most exceptional point about your answer is that a loving monotheism will inherently be more truly and perfectly monotheistic than a militant one

@Rushi -- You may have misinterpreted my discussion of Love and monotheism.  a more complex concept of God, where monotheism approaches di-theism, or polytheism, is the only way I think that theists can be compatible with the problem of evil.  Therefore the purest monotheisms cannot have a loving God.

Yeah we have disagreements. Some. IMHO they are minor and likely cultural. In my culture theism is not a big deal — {mono, poly, a, pan, whatever}. Because monotheism is a halfway house to monism — nonduality. Yeah you disapprove of non duality also and I can get behind that also. As a great ceylonese sage had said: Advaita is the one truth that becomes false on bring uttered. IOW it's true but not for discourse but rather personal meditation

Ancient humans had a multitude of beliefs in all kinds of superstitions, there was not a single god or a single theory of the history of the universe.
From all those ideas, some became cults, and some cults became religions. What determines whether any belief would become part of a cult or which cult would become a religion is not a matter of philosophy, or even theology. Theology does not allow itself to ponder that process, it starts only much later with what's called revelation scripture or prophecy, pretending those would be starting points, with prior superstitions being irrelevant and pagan.
But in secular philosophy, cults and religions are seen as the result of continued refinement, social evolution selecting among all the multiple superstitions and ideas those which had the greatest power in being replicated. As such, none of the miracles mentioned in the scriptures of Abrahamic religions were first reported in the scriptures, those were all already reported about other people not even mentioned in the scriptures.
What makes any idea or meme become successful in being replicated is difficult to predict, similar as trying to predict which video will go viral among today's youth.
However the idea of loving God's was apparently more successful in persuading people to retell it compared to other concepts of gods, in many cults and religions. Given that cults and religions rely in a service relationship between the keeper of esoteric knowledge (the guru, the priest, the shaman...) and the layman, with the service provided typically being solace, a loving god would probably make for a service that customers would most be willing to return to.
Or in simpler terms: it was the scam that worked best.

Here's the logical argument I'd give for why God's love and goodness reasonably follow from His other attributes.  It does require a few other premises first, though:

That God is all powerful and all knowing;
That God is very life itself; and,
That God has so existed from eternity past.

As for definitions, I think "love" is properly defined as good will toward someone or something; with the "will" being composed of our desires and decisions.  That is, to be entirely loving is to have a default disposition of desiring the good of others and the ultimate good of the world as a whole.  (To clarify, though, under this definition "love" is not necessarily pacifist; it would make logical sense for someone who loves good to hate the evil that destroys it, and the Bible also argues this linkage, see Amos 5:15.)  I believe "evil" is properly defined in a negative sense, as a destruction of what is good.
Given these premises and definitions, here is one argument for why God's love and goodness naturally follow, which, as I see it, is the reasoning the Bible uses, and I'll try to provide references.  In essence, for God to have existed as omnipotent, omniscient, and full of life from eternity past, I do not think He could have any inconsistency to Him at all.  In fact, the Bible makes the same argument--that "God cannot deny himself" (II Timothy 2:13).  This makes sense if we think about it, because if fault lines of inconsistency ran through God's character, then throughout eternity we would expect these to lead to fractures, and ultimately, to implosion.  But the fact is, He exists today still as omnipotent, omniscient, and full of life as ever.
In the epistemological realm, this perfect consistency correlates to absolute light (I John 1:5); that is, to God, everything is perfectly clear and apparent, with no self deceit or confusion on His part.  In the realm of communication, He is perfectly true and cannot lie (I John 2:21; Hebrews 6:18).  In morality, then, to be perfectly consistent and coherent, He must be absolutely good, loving, and just, because evil itself is a destruction of good.  Any evil in God's character would be schismatic by definition.  Since love is simply a will toward good, it is essentially a good will; and so love naturally follows from His goodness.  The apostle John makes this argument by linking hate to death (I John 3:14), going so far as to say, "Whosoever hateth his brother is a murderer: and ye know that no murderer hath eternal life abiding in him."  If we think about that for a while, it makes sense; hatred is a desire for evil toward others, or a destruction of their life, whether in whole or in part; and thus, a hateful heart is incompatible with eternal life at its core.  Now of course, none of this precludes God from being just and judging evil, or becoming angry, or even from hating evil; in fact, it seems to me quite impossible for someone to love the good without hating the evil that destroys it.  God would be less loving if He "turned a blind eye" to evil and atrocities; nor is He inconsistent for folding evil onto itself, the way one might fold a diseased cloth onto itself before getting rid of it.  Yet God's character is fully goodness and love, nor do I think it could be otherwise, even in theory.

"throughout eternity we would expect these to lead to fractures, and ultimately, to implosion." That can still happen, then. Your argument is your wishful thinking. That's faith, not philosophy.

@tkruse I'm not sure I follow...the argument is that since implosion hasn't happened yet, given an eternity past (i.e., given the premises), then it's reasonable to conclude that God's character is perfectly coherent.

So your fragile god now needs to be eternal, which cannot be proven, else he might implode tomorrow? Better suck and cover, then.

Well, at least you try to give an argument. It would still be much stronger an answer if you referenced arguments of philosophers past for the love of God (and there are plenty) instead of trying to build an original one with the Bible as sole source.

@Philip I'll be very interested to research those other arguments when I get a chance, thanks for the suggestion.

My favorite definition of Love is from the Catechism: "To Will the Good of Another"

One of the functions of a god is to provide a social relationship to otherwise unmanageable aspects of human life. For instance, communities need rain to grow crops and water animals, but wish to avoid damaging storms. Since they themselves have no control the weather, they might make appeals and offer propitiations to a god who (as a god) can control the weather. It's an effort to draw unpredictable external forces into social interaction where they can be negotiated with: a natural extension of the workings of human society.
In polytheistic eras there were different gods to manage different external events, and few of those gods expressed anything that looks like love. There were gods of war to aid against external enemies; gods of death that limit our lifespan; gods of lust and wine to satisfy our carnal urges; gods of pestilence who must be appeased out of fear; gods of cities who jealously guard their people… But as cultures shifted from polytheism to monotheism, all these multifaceted relationships became integrated into a singular deity, and then the only aspect of God that mattered was that God showed warmth and care for those who followed. I mean, think about it… if there is one deity that controls everything outside of our own control, there are really only three possibilities:

That deity is completely indifferent to us, doing whatever it wants to do for reasons unknown to us. That's scary.
That deity is antagonistic to us, trying to trip us up at every turn unless we constantly appease it. That's terrifying.
That deity loves us, trying its best to help us so long as we maintain a solid relationship to it, That's comforting.

So the monotheistic God is inevitably a loving God because that is the social relationship we humans need.

I kinda question the idea that there's a binary or natural progression between polytheism and monotheism, or that monotheistic religions approach that monotheism in any one universally-identifiable way? [citation needed] as they say. Regardless, it does feel like this is the political or historical answer, not necessarily the philosophical justification that a philosopher within those schools would give.

Because humans are altricial. "God the Father" indeed.

In philosophy some fundamental experiences are not subject to discussion. Eg. I am hungry, I am cold etc. I could be faking it of course but for myself if I am cold I am cold!
Such experiences are called incorrigible.
Love is or at least comes close to being incorrigible. Yeah people will snarkily point to divorce courts as counter evidence! But love between parents and children comes closer:
Does your mother love you?
Do you need proof?
Can she give if you demand?
Love — whether one's mother's or God's — is not a meaningful subject for intellectual discourse and "logical proof"; you have it or you dont.
However the following analogy may show a way:
Analogy
A stool is stable on 3 legs. In the same way religious practice must engage mind, heart and body.
If youre a sikh this naturally expands as
Mind — Oneness of I-world-God
Heart — Love of God
Body — sewa to fellow beings seeing all as God only
You can translate sewa as service as long as the other two legs of the stool are not neglected!
Conversely, if the love leg is weak, the others can aid.

Added Later
Some Basic History
Sikhism follows the ten gurus from Guru Nanak to Guru Gobind Singh (1469-1708).
There was no strong demarcation between the sikhs and "normal" Hindus until the martyring of Guru Arjan Dev the 5th guru in 1606.
However sikhism in its modern distinctive sense only starts with the ninth and tenth gurus after the second martyrdom of Tegh Bahadur (1675) when the last guru Guru Gobind Singh militarized the community to resist the atrocities of the mughal tyrant Aurangzeb and expecting no guru successor, 'nominated' the Sri Guru Granth Saheb (SGGS) as the eternal 'guru' from then on.
This history is needed to understand that the major author of the fundamental book of the sikhs, Guru Nanak, was very much a Hindu religious reformer, and was not trying to start some fundamentally new system.  This can be seen in the fact the names he used for God in the SGGS are the standard Hindu names, Ram and Krishna (Gobind and Hari).  It's true that the form of worship is different, with (normal) hindus commonly using icons for worship, whereas sikhism disapproves of idols. This disapproval too is completely in line with traditional Hinduism where name is considered to be higher than form and both name and form are the lower forms of God with pure Existence-Consciousness-Bliss
being the higher form.
Once it is understood that sikhism is a reform movement within Hinduism, it can be appreciated that sikhism is in line with the primary Hindu teachings eg. of the Bhagavad Gita ie. (a) karma called sewa ie selfless action, (b) bhakti called prema is love, and (c) gyana is firm knowledge of non dual Oneness is the goal.
Path from service  through love to wisdom/oneness with God
is described here:

This method of karam is acceptable, that which was instructed by Sri Bhagvan Krishna. By performing good actions —karam — one's mind becomes pure. Then a devotional spirit will reside within ones consciousness.

Sewa and prayer as a path to love

Just as a blind man may be cured by a suitable treatment a person without love can be cured by prayer and seva
SGGS Ang (section) 8

Sewa as a  path to God

One who performs selfless service, without thought of reward, shall attain his Lord and Master.
SGGS

God IS Love
ie to love is to become God

Love is the Lord's Name, love is His form, love is His abode, love is His treasure.
Sukhamani Saheb from SGGS


Love is the Lord's essence, love is His form.
Asa di Var from SGGS


None of this is philosophy. The emotional affect of the biological mother of the OP is not a philosophy argument, but totally irrelevant. Nor does philosophy need to follow the physics of household furniture. So this is all off-topic preaching.

@tkruse (1)Youre welcome to your view. And tnx for explaining the downvote. (2) You are also welcome to hate (conventional)religions, a position you take regularly (3) If you think love of God, God's love and their relation are not a basic part of philosophy of religion I suggest you consider getting yourself a basic education. Eg. Plato' symposium on love is both light and enlightening (4) if you think philosophy of religion
is not a suitable topic for this site that's a subject for a meta discussion

@tkruse On meta

As far as I see, this merely states the Sikh dogma, as opposed to explaining why the love of God is necessary, which is what the OP asked for. Like, even given the metaphor of a stool (or pillars), the question remains why we should picture anything like this if not to justify why we need three pillars, which is circular, nor does it tell us why one of them has to be love....or am I missing something?

Is not such circularity the hallmark of religion when philosophized? Eg. Why is Jesus God? Because the OT prophesies point to him. What makes the Bible the holy book (instead of GGS, Gita, Dhammapada etc).? Because it's central figure is Jesus!! If we are to have an honest discourse on philosophy of religion (for any religion) (1) it has to be emic not merely etic (2) It must accept that the central ontologies of religion are religious, no different than physics is physics-ical, math is mathematical etc. (1/2)

@PhilipKlöcking (cont) You cannot get philosophy out of the bible any more than you can get it out of the GGS. If OTOH you get it from Aquinas (say) it will be disputed by Occam or Duns Scotus. Which basically points to all these as secondary Christian sources As christian analogue to this question try the query:  Jesus says he's the Son of God. Why should I believe him? (2/2)

@PhilipKlöcking I've added some pointers to primary texts as elaboration of my central claims so that it's not merely a repetition of the "central dogma"

Probably most mothers love their children, but some don't. We can draw some reasonable conclusions about that based on how they act towards their children and what things they allow to befall their children. Watching their children starve to death, or go through other extreme suffering, seemingly for no greater good, while being able to easily to stop that, but choosing not to? At best, we'd say that's not a loving parent. I'd say that makes a pretty good analogy for God (if one exists).

@NotThatGuy Is Birds fly a false claim? What about penguins and ostriches? Exceptions do not, in a literal sense, "prove the rule" but they do not "disappear the rule" either. For the rest, theodicy is a quintessentially Christian problem. For many reasons that are not germane here. Your arguments — we've had these arguments before!— are a Christian detractor against a Christian God

@Rushi My point is against the existence of a powerful loving monotheistic God, which is what the question alludes to and which isn't specific to Christianity. Yes, we have had this back-and-forth before - you keep insisting that I'm talking specifically about Christianity, or you act like I'm not aware of the proposed existence of other gods, even though neither of those things are true. You just assert that it's true with little to no argument or evidence, or contrary to the evidence, as a way to dismiss what I'm saying without actually addressing it.

@NotThatGuy it's not so much about facts that we disagree as of emphasis. xyy-theism where xyz ∊ {poly, mono, a, pan, heno, etc} happens to apply more or less to religions across the board. But the common term, theism, is not nearly so important outside of Christianity as you imagine. This would be clearer if you considered the idiomatic term for 'atheist' in all these non Christian systems. Eg. In sikhism it's manmukh signifying a self-willed, obdurate, vain, deluded person. Ontological commitments —for or against— that dominate Christian atheist arguments, are backgrounded and hardly there

@Rushi The label of "theist" applies to anyone who accepts the existence of one or more gods, whether they adopt that label or not - I didn't say the term is important to people outside of Christianity, it's just a definition we use for the sake of facilitating communication (and it's not even a term I used in my original comment, and in my subsequent comment I only used it to refer to belief in a singular god, so I'm not sure why you bring it up). And the validity of arguments against the claims they're making (if any) is independent of whether they engage with such arguments.

@Rushi Also, you imply I have such a strong Christian bias in what I say, despite the fact that I'm just addressing the question at hand. It's like if someone asks what's the nutritional content of cauliflower, and I respond with the nutritional content of cauliflower, and you criticise me for having a cauliflower-centric bias. No, I'm just responding appropriately to what was asked.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@NotThatGuy that was funny, but to be fair: the nutritional content of cauliflower only makes sense in terms of nutritional content generally. If it was the only thing we could eat (like koala bears and eucalyptus leaves) we wouldn't give it any thought. It seems, sadly, that we can't talk about anything without bringing in everything. Perhaps that explains why people move towards religion so readily? Just an idea that occurred to me.
